# Custom fields in webform membership renewal

Tags: drupal, civimember, contacts, custom-fields, webform-civicrm

I'm starting out to create a CiviCRM system under Drupal for managing the memberships of a Photobiology Society. I have already imported contacts, organizations, memberships and contributions from the old system.
Now I should carry out the registration phase of the applications or renewals to the society through the Webform integration. No problem for the applications, while for the renewals I would like to present all the data to the old member, INCLUDING the custom ones that I had to create.
If I include an "existing contact" field, I'm able to only fill in the standard CiviCRM fields (name, address, email, phone, etc.) and not the custom ones, including the active membership.
Can someone help me and above all is it possible to do this?

Comment: I think you will need to pass membership id in the url for the membership custom fields to prepopulate

Answer (score 1):

Pinto Vasa, Welcome to CiviCRm SE. Yes its possible to include any CiviCRM custom fields on webform which is available under their respective tab of CiviCRM webform config setting. Those fields will be pre-populated on webform based on logged in user details, will be empty if its a anonymous submission or new submission if logged in. The webform can be used to populate details of specific contact by passing contact id (and checksum if the user doesn't have sufficient permission eg anonymous user or minimal permission authenticated user).

eg http://example.org/renewmembership?cid=202&cs=9f4a2e5d4d57567b6ba4468750ac128d_1585225559_168

Comment: Pradeep, thanks a lot for your prompt reply. At the moment, however, another big problem is created on the Existing contact field defined with the autocomplete widget: it seems that jquery behaves in the strangest way, for example it cannot find the beginning of a  last_name "Vas" but instead finds "asa" and in any case after the fourth character, he refuses to continue self-completion. This strange behavior changes depending on how you set the "Contact Display Field (s)" (Display Name, o Sort Name or Last Name).

Comment: I tried reinstalling Jquery Update on Drupal, and even the Chrome Dev Tool Console isn't helpful, as no errors are raised. At the moment I must first solve this problem because I have to present existings data (included the custom ones...) to the member who wants to renew and to whom I sent the contact_id and checksum by email. In our society there is no provision for managing a drupal user database, and the url recognition system is the most suitable.